# Importing 3DS Patron liquor bottle has no color, texture, glass material or label showing

Tags: import

I just bought a 3D stock file of a Patron bottle from Squid (http://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/779325) and I tried importing the 3DS format in. The bottle OBJECTS import fine and I can see the label, the liquid, the ribbon etc. is there... but unfortunately it's not reading any thing other than the objects. It has ALL the objects there -- but NOT the cork stopper material, the glass material, the color, the label graphic etc. I do have the 3DS add on turned on in user preferences.  Please help if you can. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check that the textures are set correctly in the materials?

Comment: related ?: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/how-to-import-a-model-with-textures-applied/6256#6256 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34112/how-to-use-different-texture-images

Comment: The first link you gave (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/how-to-import-a-model-with-textures-applied/6256#6256)  might have the key as it states I need to click the transparency option in materials as shown in their screen shot of Blender... however in this version of Blender 2.75 there is NO option for transparency. Is there a workaround?  Also --guess I might need to reassign the UV/maps / Textures...  not sure how to do that.